# Facebook Connect issue in IE., SS component DNB63 has been requested and should not be loaded more than once

Tags: facebook

it occurs after validation of credentials in facebook login-window triggered from facebook connect.

it says Save Device, then throw following Error.

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; InfoPath.3)
Timestamp: Fri, 31 Aug 2012 17:47:39 UTC

Message: CSS component DNB63 has been requested and should not be loaded more than once.
Line: 32
Char: 1635
Code: 0
URI: https://s-static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v2/yC/r/wn8vcRmqLA6.js

did anybody faced this issue earlier?